# Modulus of continuity of $x^2$ on $(0,1)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am working with the modulus of continuity of a function $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\omega(f,r) = \sup \{ |f(x) - f(y)| : x,y\in I \ \& \ |x-y|\leq r\}$. I am asked to prove that if $I = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = x^2$, the modulus of continuity is equal to $\omega(f,r) = 2r - r^2$ whenever $r \in (0,1)$.

The argument is obvious, you take $x_n \rightarrow 1$ and $y_n = x_n - r$ and the answer is shown. However, this is not a formal proof. Any ideas on how to write this in a formal way? I don't seem to quite grasp the concepts necessary to know how to prove this question.

Comment: to my understanding moduli of contiuty is used to somehow compare and gauge  continuous functions.ive seen its application in potential theory.also they define $L_p$ moduli of continuity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little geometric observation you can convince yourself that in order to attain max/sup with $x$ and $y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$ one has to be actually the end point meaning $1$ and so the other one is precisely $1-\delta$. Thus $|f(1)-f(1-\delta)|=|1-(1-\delta)^2|=2\delta-\delta^2$ gives you the supremum, so  $w(f,\delta)=2\delta-\delta^2$. P.S It is more common to use $\delta$ instead of $r$.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely suffice if $f(1)$ was defined. However, in this case, as $f$ is only defined over $(0,1)$, you can't do $f(1)$.

Comment: Clearly one point is not an issue. Set $F(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in(0,1)$ and $F(1)=1.$ Then $F$ is a continuous extension of $f$ and does not change the sup.